# JWTAuthServiceProvider class not found after any artisan command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7, jwt

I tried to install JWTAuth and as always I got an error that is:

`Class "Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider"` is not found

Even when I remove this package and remove everything about it from `app.php` and when I run any artisan command I get this error..

I am using Laravel 5.7

Comment: Maybe `grep -R 'JWTAuthServiceProvider' project_folder` to see if there are any instances lurking in your code. Also try `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 0):

If you published with

`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider"`
it does not work since it is for JWT version 1.0

Sometimes this may happen since you might follow JWT version 1.0 documentation but you might have installed JWT version 0.5 so try publishing with

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider"
```

for JWT version 0.5

Comment: i tried everythis, my app crashed totally nothing could work so i needed to make a new one with same db thanks god